# How to use PyInstaller with distutils

Tags: python, pyinstaller, distutils

Trying to use pyinstaller with a library that uses distutils. Can't figure out how to use the hooks to get it to bring distutils with it.

All I have in the project is main.py and the hook, which I copied from the pyinstaller hooks directory. It says it finds the hook, so I think the problem is not with the hook. I shouldn't even need the hook - main.py contains only `import distutils` so you'd think it wouldn't be a hidden import.

Here is the output of the pyinstaller command `pyinstaller main.py --additional-hooks-dir ${DIR}/pyinstaller_hooks`

```
65 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
66 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.0.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
67 INFO: wrote /home/z9/repos/test/main.spec
69 INFO: UPX is not available.
70 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/z9/repos/test', '/home/z9/repos/test']
70 INFO: checking Analysis
73 INFO: Building because hookspath changed
73 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
75 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
77 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4411 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4434 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4445 INFO: Analyzing /home/z9/repos/test/main.py
4449 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
4450 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/home/z9/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py'
4452 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4453 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4527 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
4841 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4862 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4862 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4871 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
5529 INFO: Looking for eggs
5530 INFO: Using Python library /home/z9/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
5539 INFO: Warnings written to /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/warn-main.txt
5584 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/xref-main.html
5596 INFO: checking PYZ
5598 INFO: Building because toc changed
5598 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz
6144 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
6150 INFO: checking PKG
6150 INFO: Building because /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz changed
6150 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
6173 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
6175 INFO: Bootloader /home/z9/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/zoetic/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
6175 INFO: checking EXE
6176 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because pkg is more recent
6176 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
6176 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/z9/repos/test/build/main/main
6216 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
6220 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "/home/z9/repos/test/dist/main" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
13469 INFO: Removing dir /home/z9/repos/test/dist/main
13484 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
13550 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Here is the output of running the resulting program:

```
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import distutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
[20846] Failed to execute script main
```

Am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Tried `pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import distutils`
now get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import distutils
  File "/home/z9/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/zoetic/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "distutils/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist' from 'distutils' (/home/z9/repos/test/dist/main/distutils/__init__.pyc)
[24692] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: Does executing simple "pyinstaller main.py" also gives you an error? And what is that error?

Comment: Yeah, I get the same error as the first one - "No module named `distutils`"

Comment: Do you have by any chance multiple versions of python installed in your computer?

Comment: yeah we are using virtualenv, does that matter?

Comment: Yes. It does matter. I suspect you have distutils installed in another virtualenv or python version and you are using pyinstaller in another. This can be a reason why it is saying "No module named disutils". Maybe try installing distutils again in the virtualenv you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'distutils' in pandas pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404906/importerror-no-module-named-distutils-in-pandas-pyinstaller)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyinstaller%5D+distutils